# Client/Peer communication with Wi-Fi Direct on Android

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct

I have three Android devices: A, B, and C. They are connected via Wi-Fi Direct (assuming B is the group owner).  I just have two questions:

1. Can B connect as a client to another Wi-Fi Direct group?
2. Can A or C connect as a client to another Wi-Fi Direct group?

Answer (score 5):

I've tested your issues 2 days ago.

1. B can connect to device D only if D isn't the owner of some group, and therefore D will be joined to B's group as a client.
2. When A/C are connected to B as clients, when they'll try to send a connection request to some  device D, the request will be forwarded to the group owner B to accept the connection and to also add D to the group. (This scenario was tested when D was in the range of B AND A/C).
   When D isn't in the range of B but is in the range of A/C, the request of A/C will be canceled and the connection of A/C with B will disconnect.

That's the scenario we were facing when trying to understand the behavior of Wi-Fi Direct.

Hope that I helped you.
If someone tests it and knows something else, I would appreciate to know it.

Answer (score 0):

I read this in the [white paper](http://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/white-papers/wi-fi-certified-wi-fi-direct%E2%84%A2-personal-portable-wi-fi%C2%AE-technology-2010) that I downloaded from WiFi alliance:

> Concurrent Connections and Multiple Groups.
>
> A Wi-Fi Direct Device that can be in a Group while maintaining a WLAN infrastructure connection at the same time is considered a Concurrent Device. For example, a laptop connected directly to a printer while simultaneously using a WLAN connection is operating as a Concurrent Device. Concurrent connections may be supported by a single radio and may support connections on different channels.
> Concurrent operation requires support for multiple and distinct MAC entities, one for operation as a WLAN-STA and one for operating as a Wi-Fi Direct device. There are several approaches developers can take to implement multiple MAC entities. For example, maintaining two separate physical MAC entities, each associated with its own PHY entity, or using a single PHY entity encompassing two virtual MAC entities. These different approaches are beyond the scope of the P2P Specification.
> Concurrent Devices may participate in multiple Groups simultaneously. The P2P Specification does not describe the mechanism for this capability – implementation is specific to the vendor.

---

So it is possible connecting two group owners but both of them should be concurrent device.

Comment: Do you have a link to the white paper that you can add to this answer?

Comment: I download the white paper here 
http://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/white-papers/wi-fi-certified-wi-fi-direct%E2%84%A2-personal-portable-wi-fi%C2%AE-technology-2010