# Is it possible to connect two or more WiFi Direct groups?

Tags: android, p2p, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am currently experimenting with WiFi-Direct (WiFiP2p) for a project I'm working on and wanted to know if one can create bridge between groups, thus joining them together?

Based upon the [white paper](http://www.wi-fi.org/system/files/wp_Wi-Fi_Direct_20101025_Industry.pdf) released by the WiFi Alliance, it should be possible (though "The P2P Specification does not describe the mechanism for this capability – implementation is specific to the vendor"). I have looked through the internet and have found some answers ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13642577/1203078), [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/6wMTw6RJ5h8), etc.) but I feel that none are particularly conclusive. Looking at Andoid's API hasn't helped much either.

The scenario I'm trying to create is having a client from one group connect to another group as well. Given 4 devices (A, B, C, D), where A and B are in a group, with A being group owner, and C and D are in a group managed by D:

- C connects to A. Thus 2 groups have been joined with C acting as a bridge.

Is this possible?

1. http://www.wi-fi.org/system/files/wp_Wi-Fi_Direct_20101025_Industry.pdf
2. [Client/Peer communication with Wi-Fi Direct on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13642577/1203078)
3. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/6wMTw6RJ5h8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-platform/MdbeSZRFD-M). According to this link when C connects to A it is no longer a group member of the group managed by D. Without belonging to the same group two device cannot communicate with each other.

Also if it was possible to have multiple group owners in a wifi-direct group then they could simultaneously communicate with each other along with their group members. This is optional implementation in wifi-direct according to their whitepaper. It says:

> Wi-Fi Direct Device maintains membership in multiple Groups
>   simultaneously: Optional

But in case of Android's implementation of wifi-direct, having multiple group owner is not possible. See the [Andrdoid's reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pGroup.html). 
It says:

> A p2p group consists of a single group owner and one or more clients.

Comment: And in the last story: "new p2p connection between device B & Device C." A will be left along? Is it also possible to say to A something like: you may join the new group "B & C"...?

Answer (score -1):

Belonging to a WFD group is equal to being in the same Channel/FREQ as that group's group owner..., so if the group owners can independently choose their operating channel, then the group members from one group cannot reach the group members from the other group (& vice-versa).

Answer (score -1):

hello our way to resolve the problem is create legacy wifi direct group and connect with normal wifi in another group.
Another problem is the ipv4 conflict, we resolved with the ipv6.

https://github.com/giangiu25307/Connection

Comment: riccardo fasolo, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)