# Can WiFi direct group owner connect to other device group?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

If one device has created a WiFi direct group (access point) this device can connect at the same time to other device group?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR - theoretically yes, practically (in Android) no.**

Group `OWNER` and `CLIENT` operation mode specify a role of a node within WifiDirect connection.

In theory it should be possible although it would mean that a single node can simultaneously connect to more than one WifiDirect group (your picture represents 3 groups). And 'in theory' means that an OPTIONAL (according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21736639/1993204) and WifiDirect whitepaper) feature has been implemented.

> Wi-Fi Direct Device maintains membership in multiple Groups simultaneously: Optional

[image: 3 groups shown on author's image]

Ok. Back to Android (since I can see it in your tag): from my experience, I know that Android's implementation of WifiP2p will not let you get two simultaneous connections with two seperate nodes.